# Событие перелистывания Pivot WPF

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8.1

У меня есть `Pivot` с привязкой к данным.

```
<Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
   <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="Перелистни меня!"/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

В code-behind, допустим, простой List:

```
List<int> MyList = new List() {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Для упрощения, список - это просто 5 элементов, не важно каких. Просто построятся 5 страничек Пивота, содержимое не важно.

Как можно назначить и отследить событие перелистывания между элементами этого `Pivot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно событие [`SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.selectionchanged(v=vs.105).aspx).

```
private void pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pivot.SelectedIndex);
}
```